# How to do Packet Retry when the Acknowledgement has not been received

Tags: c++, linux

I want to Retry a packet transmission on UDP if neither ACK nor NACK is received. Then in that scenario i will wait for 500 milliseconds till i retransmit the packet.

Comment: If you want to, what's stopping you? We're not going to write it for you, but we'll help you fix your code if you post it.

Answer (score 1):

UDP is "fire and forget".  You have to manage acknowledgements at the application layer.  So, if you don't get an ACK in a timely fashion, just send it again.  Add logic for duplicate reception, etc.

Comment: Thanx Mark , but can you please guide me on how i can resend the packet ACK is not  received in time

Comment: same exact way you sent it the first time.  1) send packet, set a timer 2) wait for ACK, 3A) receive ACK and all is OK -or- 3B) timer fires, start again at 1)